# How to code in foxpro for ftp file transfer

Tags: ftp, foxpro

```
I have the following code to get image from another pc.
!@echo off
    !md c:\edrs\memphoto
    !echo InHouse>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo abc>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo prompt>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo lcd C:\EDRS\memphoto>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo cd memphoto>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo mget &varphoto>> d:\ftp.txt
    !echo bye>> d:\ftp.txt
    !@echo on
    !ftp -s:d:\ftp.txt 172.16.1.11
    *!dir
    !del  d:\ftp.txt
```

This code downloads file to c:\edrs\memphoto directory of a local pc from another pc.

```
!@echo off
!md c:\edrs\memphoto
!echo InHouse>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo abc>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo prompt>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo lcd C:\EDRS\memphoto>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo cd memphoto>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo mget &varphoto>> c:\ftp.txt
!echo bye>> c:\ftp.txt
!@echo on
!ftp -s:c:\ftp.txt 172.16.1.11
*!dir
!del  c:\ftp.txt
```

The above code cannot download file to c:\edrs\memphoto of a pc from another pc. Another code is given bellow:

```
!@echo off
!md c:\edrs\memphoto
!echo InHouse>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo abc>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo prompt>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo lcd C:\EDRS\memphoto>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo cd memphoto>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo mget &varphoto>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!echo bye>> c:\edrs\ftp.txt
!@echo on
!ftp -s:c:\edrs\ftp.txt 172.16.1.11
*!dir
!del  c:\edrs\ftp.txt
```

This works fine.
Is there anyone who can say what the reason is?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not need to write a file in a directory" ... do you mean streaming into a local buffer?

Comment: This code creates a file ftp.txt in D directory of a local pc.
 So if a directory is write protected then this code does not work. I need to code in such a way that does not have any directory dependency. I don't know what is meant by "streaming into a local buffer ". If it does not have any directory access dependency then it is ok.

Comment: I need a code in foxpro that will transfer file but does not have any directory write access dependency.

Comment: Most likely, the C drive of the other machine isn't shared, so you can't write to it.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to transfer file without creating this ftp.txt file in any directory? Though I'm not sure I think !ftp -s:c:\edrs\ftp.txt 172.16.1.11 line is responsible to execute ftp.txt file. Is it possible run the code written in ftp.txt without writing in ftp.txt file?

Answer (score 0):

You are telling an FTP server to give you a file over the wire. Where would that file go if you aren't going to store it in a directory? If it has to go in a directory, you need write access to that directory. There isn't some magic way to bypass OS file system permissions. Therefore your problem is a file system permissions issue and you need to check for write access to your chosen directory first and handle a failure accordingly, before even starting an FTP transfer.

Comment: I think, I am not able to express my opinion. My office told me that your C drive has no write permission. But I am not sure. The code I have mentioned here creates edrs\memphoto directory in c drive. But it cannot create a ftp.txt file in C drive if I change d:\ftp.txt with c:\ftp.txt and also cannot transfer file. That's why I change the code as d:\ftp.txt. Which creates a file ftp.txt in d directory and also can transfer file in C directory. I am thinking whether it is possible to transfer file by not creating this ftp.txt